# How to interpret probability column in spark logistic regression prediction?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I'm getting predictions through `spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.predict`.  A number of the rows have the `prediction` column as `1.0` and `probability` column as `.04`.  The `model.getThreshold` is `0.5` so I'd assume the model is classifying everything over a `0.5` probability threshold as `1.0`.

**How am I supposed to interpret a result with a 1.0 `prediction` and a `probability` of 0.04?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The probability column from performing a `LogisticRegression` should contain a list with the same length as the number of classes, where each index gives the corresponding probability for that class. I made a small example with two classes for illustration:

```scala
case class Person(label: Double, age: Double, height: Double, weight: Double)
val df = List(Person(0.0, 15, 175, 67), 
      Person(0.0, 30, 190, 100), 
      Person(1.0, 40, 155, 57), 
      Person(1.0, 50, 160, 56), 
      Person(0.0, 15, 170, 56), 
      Person(1.0, 80, 180, 88)).toDF()

val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("age", "height", "weight"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .select("label", "features")
val df2 = assembler.transform(df)
df2.show

+-----+------------------+
|label|          features|
+-----+------------------+
|  0.0| [15.0,175.0,67.0]|
|  0.0|[30.0,190.0,100.0]|
|  1.0| [40.0,155.0,57.0]|
|  1.0| [50.0,160.0,56.0]|
|  0.0| [15.0,170.0,56.0]|
|  1.0| [80.0,180.0,88.0]|
+-----+------------------+

val lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8)
val Array(testing, training) = df2.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

val model = lr.fit(training)
val predictions = model.transform(testing)
predictions.select("probability", "prediction").show(false)


+----------------------------------------+----------+
|probability                             |prediction|
+----------------------------------------+----------+
|[0.7487950501224138,0.2512049498775863] |0.0       |
|[0.6458452667523259,0.35415473324767416]|0.0       |
|[0.3888393314864866,0.6111606685135134] |1.0       |
+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

Here are the probabilities as well as the final prediction made by the algorithm. The class that have the highest probability in the end is the one predicted.

Comment: Hi Shaido. How do we associate each of the probability to its corresponding class ? As we see here prob[0] is actually from class 0 and prob[1] from class 1. Where does it says prob[0] does not correspond to class 1 ?

Comment: Good question. It seems, in a binary classification task, that some algorithms associate by default probability higher than a certain threshold with class "0". Which is basically useless...

Comment: @guiotan: In case of binary classification, the predicted class will always be the one with higher probability. I.e., in the code above, `prediction` 0.0 and 1.0 corresponds to labels 0.0 and 1.0 while the associated probability for each prediction will be the highest one in the `probability` column.

Comment: is there a method that gives 1 value between 0 & 1 for the probability column? Like another column ('combined_probability') that results in a prob below .5 for the first two predictions and .5 or above for the last row?

Comment: @sAguinaga: You can simply take the first element (or second if you want the other order) of the array to get what you want.