# I want to understand the probability results that we get from the logistic regression

Tags: probability, logistic-regression, propensity-score-matching

I got results from a logistic regression model as 0 or 1. I want to use their probabilities as propensity score for my marketing work. When I see the results, I noticed there are two probabilities, I want to know which probability is the probability for predicting 1 and which is for 0. Below is a rough sample of results that I see, which confused me.

```
#actual | prediction | probability
#0      | 1          | [89, 11]
#1      | 1          | [76, 34]
#0      | 0          | [80, 20]
#0      | 1          | [99, 1]
```

Here first probability number is higher than second, but I don't know which is the one for predicting 1 vs predicting 0. How to make sure I am taking probability of 1 and then rank ordering the observations to take highest propensity customers?

Comment: How did you calculate the probability ?

Comment: I got these probabilities from LogisitcRegression function in pyspark. I saved these probabilities to hive dataset. But there is no clear pattern as to which is probability for 0 and which i the one for 1.

Comment: Check on this link. Hope you find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059312/how-to-interpret-probability-column-in-spark-logistic-regression-prediction

Comment: I noticed that the results are not well arranged in pyspark. However, when I exported the results to hive database, I noticed that the first probability is probability of predicting 0, and second probability is probability of predicting 1.